# Latex symbols on axes

Tags: matlab

I am trying to display `\mathscr{R}` (stylish R) on a figure's axes. I tried

```
ylab=ylabel('$\mathscr{R}$','Interpreter','latex','Fontsize',15,'rot', 0);
```

but it doesn't work. I've been told it's possible to do it with \psfrag but I couldn't understand if this is a a posteriori action...
How would you do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `mathcal` instead of `mathscr`:

```
ylab = ylabel('$\mathcal{R}$','Interpreter','latex','Fontsize',15,'rot', 0);
```

It seems that the MATLAB LaTeX interpreter has problems dealing with the latter.

Comment: But at least it works. Matlab seems to have problems with mathscr.

Comment: Of course the symbols are different. Does anyone know how it would be possible to display \mathscr{R} ?

Comment: The problem is described here: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=6778243. It seems like this requires a package... and it also looks like it's very difficult to install one on the Matlab interpreter: https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/353532-how-to-include-custom-latex-usepackage-in-matlab-e-g-labels-of-figure